# Removing certain files on startup

Tags: startup, boot, delete-file

How do you, on startup, remove certain files from the computer. I guess you use stdlib but I can't find any functions for deleting files.

So. How do you delete files when the computer boots up ?

Comment: It would help to know what you mean with _computer_. What OS are you talking about? There are many out there.

Comment: OS? Most have the ability to execute a number script files on startup; a script file can have shell commands to remove the files you want to remove.